# Server tags not working inside asp controls

Tags: asp.net, hidden-field, server-tags

Alrighty to make this quick:

- I want to set start and end dates for a calendar extender dynamically on-change or on page load
- the values are put into hidden fields on the .ascx and populated during page load in an if not postback
- one set of calendar extenders is in the item template field of a grid view call this **set A**
- the others are in a normal html table - **set b**

**set a and set b** have flags `StartDate="<%# hfStart.value%>" EndDate="<%# hfEnd.value%>"`

**set a** in the item template of a grid view column works like a charm

**set b**  in the HTML table doesn't appear to work at all

What gives?

So far I have tried other server tags with the same code inside but I am obviously missing the salient detail. Why does one work and not the other?

UPDATE: Tried

- `CDate(hfstart.value).ToString` with <%: and <%= tags
- `<%= hfstart.value %>`

Unless I misunderstand, <%= will fire at the very END of the asp.net life cycle stopping it from being useful in this context.

Comment: I should point out that of course I can handle this in code behind, I want to know what I'm missing about server tags and ASP

Comment: I think you're missing some `%` characters from your server tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out you DO need to use `<%# %>` within asp tags as others like `<% %>` and `<%= %>` execute at the end of the ASP.NET life cycle and get spit out the buffer to god knows where. When using `<%# %>` however, the asp control needs to be `DataBound();` at the appropriate time.

This happens automatically for controls modeled in the `<item template>` tags in the gridview because everything within the gridview is bound on its `gridview.DataBound()` command.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be because you're using the `<%# %>` tags which are for data binding?  This would explain why they work in the GridView, because it supports data binding.

However in a basic HTML table you should use `<% %>` tags instead, or `<%= %>` to call a method.

For full details of the tag types, try [this reference](http://weblogs.asp.net/ahmedmoosa/archive/2010/10/06/embedded-code-and-inline-server-tags.aspx).

Comment: To be clear, the data binding is in asp:calendarextender tags which are in turn inside the HTML table or gridview