# Declaratively access page properties data binding inside repeater

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, webforms, repeater

I have a public property on an ASP.NET Forms page. I can access this page property declaratively with the following code:

> ```
> <asp:Image ID="PageImage" runat="server" ImageUrl="<%# MyProperty %>" />
> ```

However, once I put this same code inside a repeater, it does not work. I seek an explanation and a solution.

*** Update ***

The Eval is not needed and throws an eerror. You can just reference MyProperty. However, you must call DataBind on the page. Once you do that the above syntax works outside the repeater but returns empty inside the repeater.

Unfortunately, I'm no longer able to reproduce this bug. My hypothesis at this time is that the repeater didn't have any data bound to it, so it wasn't rendering.

Comment: how do you assign a value to your property ? could you add that code as well ?

Comment: @Ali It is set on page load. Again, I move the code outside repeater, it works. Inside repeater, the data is not set.

Comment: please upload a bit more of your code, only by looking at this control no one could help. add your aspx and related code behind here.

Comment: @CurtisWhite Did you try my suggestion below?

Comment: Add the markup for your repeater, and show the code which calls `DataBind()` on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the syntax I was sure that didn't work appears to work just fine now. My hypothesis is that the repeater didn't have any data bound too it, so the data wasn't display. The page had several repeaters on it and that may have been the cause of my confusion. Once you Page.Databind() and also ensure the repeater has data the original syntax works.

Update:
Interestingly, the code expression syntax <%: and <%= allow page properties to be accessed without data binding.

Answer (score 3):

There is more going on here than meets the eye :) Take this code and paste it into a new empty asp.net webforms project brand new webforms page:

```
    <script runat="server">
        protected string MyProperty
        {
            get
            {
                return "SUCCESS";
            }
        }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rTest.DataSource = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
            rTest.DataBind();
        }
    </script>
    <%: MyProperty  %><br />
    <asp:Literal ID="ltrlTest" runat="server" Text='<%# MyProperty %>' /><br />
    <asp:Repeater runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%# MyProperty %>" /><br />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

You get as output:

```
SUCCESS

SUCCESS
SUCCESS
SUCCESS
```

Why? Well the syntax you have provided is for databinding, and only works when a control has its DataBind() method called. I tried and tried and could not get your original syntax to work (hence the empty line output) so unless I've got something wrong your code snippet would only work inside a usercontrol or a page/control that is being data-bound.

As you can see from the example you can totally access those properties from inside a repeater template, and you can output that property to the page using `=` or `:` but to get things to work the way you described needs more magic than what the default scenario is.

Take a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19800526/server-tags-not-working-inside-asp-controls), and take a look at the databinding expression syntax area on [this msdn article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976112).

Now if I add `ltrlTest.DataBind()` to page load I *will* get 5 successes output. Thats the only way the `<%#` syntax will work.

Hope that helps clear things up.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add. You must call Page.DataBind() to get the original syntax to work. With Page.DataBind(), you can use <%# Myproperty %> or <%# Eval("myProperty") %> and both work fine outside the repeater. Inside the repeater, they cause a databinding runtime error. I'm still studying your answer to see if it qualifies.

Comment: You must also have data in your repeater for it to show up. I believe that is your problem. Unfortunately, now the original syntax is working for me but I tested it extensively previously and it didn't work. Perhaps I was hitting the same "bug" as no items in the repeater. And the Eval syntax does not work.

Comment: Yes, any control that you want to have `<%# variable %>` evaluated will have to have it's databind method called, whether on the page or in a control. And yes your databound templated controls need to have data for the template to evaluate. Cheers!

Comment: Interestingly, it is possible to use <%: and <%= to access the page properties without data binding. Not sure how I missed that but just discovered it.